# How to make a Pipe with Regex in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, angular2-pipe

I'm trying to make a Pipe that would match the inputted text with `Regex` and then display the logic. If not found, it shouldn't do anything.

So, the `Regex` should match something like `(m)` or multiple: `(n) (2) (abc)` and then display the logic. Let's say that the "keywords" are:

`(m) (n) (2) (abc)` - only these, not the `a-z` or `A-Z`

What I've made so far:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name:'regMatch'})
export class RegMatch implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, arg?: any): any {
      //CODE HERE  
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

EDIT: **if a matching is found an image should be displayed using Popover:** https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-popover

**If not, leave it as it is.**

Comment: Can you please explain what _display the logic_ mean? Also, add the expected output.

Comment: Give me a sec, I'll edit.

Comment: There you go mate, edited. :)

Answer (score 1):

First I must say that I do not know anything about angular2-pipe specifically.

However if you are just looking for a JS way to loop through matches to process them you can use this regular expression: `\((.+?)\)` ([example](https://regex101.com/r/4idjQF/1)).

This can be utilized like below:

```
var targetText = "(word1) other words (word2)";
var reg = new RegExp(/\((.+?)\)/);   
var result;
while((result = reg.exec(targetText)) !== null) {
    var matchedContents = result[1]; //this will be the inside of each set of ()
    console.log(matchedContents);
    //Outputs:
    //word1
    //word2
    //DO Something...
}
```

Again I'm not sure about Pipes and how this can specifically be used for your case but I hope it helps.